# UITabBar selectionIndicatorImage with 3 bars creating unwanted padding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I have a UITabBar with 3 bars in my application. What I am trying to do is implementing a custom selectionIndicatorImage. Everything is fine except for the last bar where I get a weird 1 pt padding to the right.

**Example**

[image: UITabBar]

**Code**

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-test.png"]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-selected.png"]];
```

**Dimensions**

*tabbar-test.png* 320x49 and 640x98

*tabbar-selected.png* 107x49 and 214x98

Comment: check the answer of this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035302/uitabbar-selectionindicatorimage-padding

Answer (score 0):

Here are some questions similar to yours:

[How do I remove UITabBarItem selectionImage padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886940/how-do-i-remove-uitabbaritem-selectionimage-padding)

[UITabBar selectionIndicatorImage padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035302/uitabbar-selectionindicatorimage-padding)

I met this issue and did not find a nice solution. At last, I use a 3rd part controller:

https://github.com/robbdimitrov/RDVTabBarController