# ios development in- remove the padding of a tabBar image icon

Tags: ios

I am trying to create a tabBar for my application.
I have created the needed images(60x60) and (30x30) and named them appropriately.
the problem I encounter is that the icons has black padding around it.
I have tried the following solutions:

```
 [tabBarItem1 setImageInsetsLUIEdgeInsetMake(-6,-6,6,6);]
```

but it only shifts the position of the image but it still does not span the full tabBarItem size.
I have also tried setting the indicator image to a a different image with setSelectionIndicatorImage.

also I have tried changing the frame of the tabBarItem with:

```
CGRect frame = self.tabBar.frame;
frame.origin.x = -6;
frame.size.width = frame.size.width+12;
self.tabBar.frame = frame;
```

but nothing have been changed.
 I have found this thread:
[UITabBar selectionIndicatorImage padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035302/uitabbar-selectionindicatorimage-padding)
 but it looks quite complicated.
I have tried the second and third solution with no luck.

in the third solution it is offered to:
"add your image as a subview to the tabbar:
  how do I do that?

I'll appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am using this method for my UITabBar:

```
[tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage];
```

I am creating and resizing my images to a specific frame and I can go all the way up to the tabBarItem's frame to completely replace it.